# WiFi takes long time to reconnect

Tags: android, wifi

I want to achieve a higher network connection uptime in my Android app. When a user is at the edge of WiFi coverage, the phone loses the connection. My app detects this correctly.

When the users walks into coverage again, it sometimes takes a long time (several minutes) before connection to my network is re-establish. In the Android WiFi manager it sometimes stays in state "Disconnected" (not "Turned off") for a long time, before switching to "Connected". The network is a standard WPA2 network.

I've tries something like this. The outer class executes a ConnectionExecuter each time connection is lost.

```
private void saveConnectionInfo() {
    connectionInfo = wiFiManager.getConnectionInfo();
}

private class ConnectExecuter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Do not return before WiFi is enabled and connected
        while(!wiFiManager.isWifiEnabled() || !connected()) {
            try {
                logger.debug(TAG, "Enable");
                //Checks is WiFi is disabled, and turns it on in that case.
                WiFiEnablementManager.assureWiFiEnabled(wiFiManager);
                Thread.sleep(2500);
                //if WiFi is not connected then connect to the previous network
                logger.debug(TAG, wiFiManager.getConnectionInfo().toString());
                if(!connected()) {
                    logger.debug(TAG, "Reconnecting to network id: " + connectionInfo);
                    wiFiManager.enableNetwork(connectionInfo.getNetworkId(), true);
                    wiFiManager.reconnect();
                }
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error(TAG, e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean connected() {
        if (wiFiManager.getConnectionInfo() != null && connectionInfo != null) {
            return wiFiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId() == connectionInfo.getNetworkId();
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class WiFiEnablementManager {
    public static final ILogger logger = new Logger(WiFiEnablementManager.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void assureWiFiEnabled(WifiManager wifiManager) {

        if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            logger.info("WiFi status disabled: Enabling...");
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to help on Android 2.2, but does not work on 4.0. Also the sleep statements (2500 ms and 3000 ms) might not really be justified. Any input welcome.

Comment: It can be several minutes.

Comment: The WifiManager uses a state machine, and it posts the states in the log. Look for supplicant_states. The behavior differs between phones, but from the states you can probably figure out what exactly is happening. Once you know, you may think of a solution.